# Counting elements in a sublist of strings

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

Hi I am learning list comprehension in Python and I got myself a 2 dimensional list of strings:

```
a="agagaffsst555s5s"
b="jkkjsd675sggd"
c="flflfkisisud787782ssa"
d="glgjdusgygd4562381djakughduiytywy"
e="hjashjyyd665656452hhf"
f="687255365165417gsafvx7787878"

mylist=[[a,b],[c,d,e],[f,a,d],[d]]
```

And now I would like to get a list `mylist2` of the same dimension as `mylist` but containing sums of characters of all the strings in sublists, so that:
`mylist2[0]=len(mylist[0][0]) + len(mylist[0][1])`

I tried writing a comprehension:

```
mylist2=[sum(len(mylist[i][j])) for j in range(len(mylist[i])) for i in range(len(mylist))]
```

and it doesn't work. I guess I am using `sum` function wrongly as well

Comment: show the full desired output of `mylist2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions). Then, take the sum of elements in each sublist to get the corresponding total number of characters. Furthermore, I am presenting a shorter simplified version *without* using `range(len(...))`. You can directly loop over the list elements

```
mylist2 = [sum([len(j) for j in subl]) for subl in mylist] 
# [29, 75, 77, 33]
```

If you don't want the sum, then just remove the `sum()` command

```
mylist2 = [[len(j) for j in subl] for subl in mylist]  
# [[16, 13], [21, 33, 21], [28, 16, 33], [33]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
mylist2 = list(list(map(len, i)) for i in mylist)
```

**Output** :

```
[[16, 13], [21, 33, 21], [28, 16, 33], [33]]
```

To get the sum for each sub-list :

```
mylist2 = list(sum(list(map(len, i))) for i in mylist)
```

**Output** :

```
[29, 75, 77, 33]
```

Answer (score 0):

I will join each items in the list and get the length.

```
mylist=[[a,b],[c,d,e],[f,a,d],[d]]
mylist2=[len(''.join(i)) for i in mylist] 
mylist2

Result:
[29, 75, 77, 33]
```